# fix Invalid S.M.A.R.T. checksum

Tags: osx, smartctl

So whenever I run `smartctl` I always get this error like this for example when running `smartctl -l selftest /dev/disk0`:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Warning! SMART Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3679         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3676         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3676         -
```

Comment: Umount your device then check it with `fsck`.

Comment: @GAD3R this has absolutely nothing to do with the file system, so `fsck` won’t help.

Comment: Is it a new drive or did you buy it used? Sometimes people sell drives with failure history on ebay with tampered smart data. Maybe it would go away if you run enough short tests to fill the log entirely (roughly 30 entries). Otherwise just ignore as long as the log still shows up...

Answer (score 3):

The SMART Self-Test Log Structure is something that is returned by the disk firmware, not a regular file.

The only way to fix it would be to update the disk firmware to a version that creates the checksum correctly. You should check the support pages of the disk manufacturer to see if firmware updates are available, and if so, if they can be installed without losing all data currently on the disk.

As frostschutz said in his comment, if you bought this drive used, the previous owner might have tampered with the SMART data to make the drive saleable.

You might want to run the SMART self-tests the disk has available: once the tests complete, the disk firmware should update the log structure, hopefully including the checksum.

Linux `smartmontools` developers say that a SMART checksum error like this may also be caused by OS/chipset/disk controller bugs.